# tungsten replicate from mysql slave to vertica - does not seem to look at relay-log?

Tags: mysql, replication, master-slave, vertica, tungsten-replicator

I am playing with mysql and vertica and have a master/slave mysql pair that is running with mixed binlog format (default settings).

To replicate this to the vertica database for some analysis tasks, I was considering tungsten.

The master is busy with read/write requests from the app, and the slave is just recording whats happening, so ideally I want to run the tungsten replicator on the mysql slave as it is only reading as well.

Tungsten requires the binlog to be in row based format, and so I enabled a row based binlog on the slave, which creates the binlog and the relay-binlog files. So the slave reads mixed binlog from the master, applies to its database and also keeps the changes in the relay-binlog in row based format. Everything fine so far.

When I use the standard -a --master-slave argument it appears to be only looking at the binlogs that only contain things that happened locally on the slave, but not the relay-binlogs.

The documentation and posts I found all point to running tungsten on the master, and to use it for replication throughout without using mysql master/slave, rather than that hybrid mode I have in mind.

However I would prefer to keep whats working and just add tungsten as a bridge replicating from mysql slave to vertica.

How would I configure that?

How do I tell it what tables I want to replicate from the slave to vertica, rather than replicate all?

Configuration detail:

/etc/my.cnf of slave:

```
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
log-bin=/var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days=7

# for tungsten replicator we need row based binlogs on the slave
binlog-format=row
## Server timezone is GMT.
#default-time-zone='+00:00'
# Tables default to UTF8.
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_general_ci

server-id=3
```

The script I use to stage tungsten:

```
tungsten-replicator-2.1.2-30/tools/tungsten-installer --master-slave -a \
  --service-name=mysql2vertica \
  --master-host=testslave1 \
  --cluster-hosts=testslave1 \
  --datasource-user=tungsten \
  --datasource-password=supersecret \
  --home-directory=/opt/tungsten \
  --buffer-size=1000 \
  --java-file-encoding=UTF8 \
  --java-user-timezone=CDT \
  --mysql-use-bytes-for-string=false \
  --svc-extractor-filters=colnames,pkey \
  --property=replicator.filter.pkey.addPkeyToInserts=true \
  --property=replicator.filter.pkey.addColumnsToDeletes=true \
  --start-and-report
```

It seems to start fine, says its online, but only copies what is in binlog but not relay-binlog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're successfully running Tungsten on our MySQL slave, so what you're looking to do is definitely possible.

By default the slave [does not copy incoming changes to the outgoing binlog](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_log-slave-updates) where Tungsten is expecting them. Try adding:

```
log-slave-updates=TRUE
```

to your my.cnf file.

Comment: Awesome! I now remember having seen that statement recommended somewhere and then lost track of it. With it, it now works as expected.

Comment: Now all I have to do is figure out why replication fails on the vertica side with Unable to delete data from stage table:...

Comment: Figured that out too, need to run ddl-scan with both the staging and the non-staging template. Next task: how to declare which tables to extract and apply rather than all... :)